# Print numbers with spaces in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of numbers that I want to print as follows:

```
          1
          1
          3
         11
         58
        451
      4 461
     49 957
    598 102
  7 437 910
 94 944 685
```

Currently I achieve this by the following ugly code:

```
for count in counts:
    s = str(count)[::-1]
    s = ' '.join([s[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0,len(s),3)][::-1])
    print('{:>11}'.format(s))
```

Is there anyway that `format` can achieve this immediately? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: It doesn't matter _how_ ugly code is when you can hide it in a well-documented function :-)

Comment: That is true, of course. But one of the credos of Python is simplicity, and that doesn't look simple at all. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the thousand-separator in the string formatter and replace that to your likings like this:

```
>>> nums = (1, 3, 11, 58, 451, 4461, 49957, 598102, 7437910, 94944685)
>>> for num in nums:
        print('{:>11,}'.format(num).replace(',', ' '))

          1
          3
         11
         58
        451
      4 461
     49 957
    598 102
  7 437 910
 94 944 685
```